# Is $\sf \Gamma_0$ the proof theoretic ordinal of this kind of predicative class theory?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, foundations, axioms, ordinal-analysis

Adopting the approach of Mono-sorted $\sf NBG$, define *set*s as elements of classes, then axiomatize:

**Extensionality**,  **Predicative Class comprehension**, **emptyset**, in the usual manner along mono-sorted $\sf NBG$, denote the class of all sets by $V$, add **powerset** axiom as: $$\forall a \in V: \{y \in V \mid y \subseteq a \} \in V$$

, add axiom of **infinity** asserting that the class union of the intersectional class of all classes having $\emptyset$ among their elements and closed under powerset operator, is a set; call this set $V_\omega$.

Then add an axiom of **Hierarchy** stating that every set belongs an *initial* stage of the cumulative hierarchy, the latter is simply an element of the intersectional class of all classes with $\emptyset$ and $V_\omega$ among their elements that are closed under powerset operator. The *final* stage of the cumulative hierarchy is $V$.

Now the rank of a stage is simply defined as the class of all ordinal elements of that stage.

The rank $\rho$ of a *class* is simply the rank of the first stage the class appears as a subclass of.

Now we add the axiom schema of predicative specification:

**Predicative Specification:** if $\phi^\alpha(y)$ is a formula in which $x$ doesn't occur free, and $y$ occur free, having all its parameters among $\vec{w}$, and all quantifiers bounded $\in V$ and also rank bounded by $< \alpha$, then:

$\forall \alpha \in V \forall \vec{w} \in V \forall x: \\ \rho`` \vec{w} \leq \alpha  \land x=\{y \in V \mid \phi^\alpha (y)\} \land \rho(x)=\alpha  \\\implies x \in V $

Now add the axiom that every set is both **countable** and **well orderable**.

> Is "$\sf ON \geq \Gamma_0$" a theorem of this theory?

Where $\sf ON$ is the class of all ordinal elements of $V$, and  $\sf \Gamma_0$ is Feferman–Schütte ordinal.

Comment: How is the powerset axiom predicative? It defines a power set by picking out its elements from $V$, a class to which the power set being constructed belongs. This is textbook impredicativity.

Comment: @NikWeaver, by predicativity in this theory I meant within the set world, the occurrence of $V$ as a bound on the quantifiers, and in $y \in V \mid \phi$ is exempted from violation of predicativity here. The point is even if we consider those occurrances of $V$ as outright violations of predicativity, then does it matter, would that make the theory go beyond expected strengths of predicative theories, the general idea is that those occurrances of $V$ are innocent and do not substantially violate predicativity.